# BibTex article entry doesn't display the title

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm writing a bibliography using BibTex and I have the following entry:

```
@article{ofori2014impact,
title={The impact of climate change on cocoa production in West Africa},
author={Ofori-Boateng, Kenneth and Insah, Baba},
journal={International Journal of Climate Change Strategies and Management},
volume={6},
number={3},
pages={296--314},
year={2014},
publisher={Emerald Group Publishing Limited}
}
```

which is actually formulated by the citation tool in Google Scholar. The document then displays everything except the title. It works with other types of entries such as books or inproceedings, but every article has this problem.

I've tried different styles of the bibliography, but this doesn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE, could you add a minimal working example? Without that it is difficult to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: Many styles in chemistry omit the titles of `@article`s/journal papers. Maybe you only tried those. Without an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864), a short yet complete example document that reproduces exactly what you are seeing we can't say a lot more. I can only add that I tested the entry from the question and the title displayed beautifully.

Comment: Sure, a working example of a book is:
`@book{fwt1989simulation,
  title={Simulation of ecophysiological processes of growth in several annual crops},
  author={FWT Penning de Vries},
  volume={29},
  year={1989},
  publisher={Int. Rice Res. Inst.}
}`
I used a default style, the chicago, plain and siam. Also if I change the type of entry of the first example to inproceeding, then it displays the title, but of course the rest of the format is not what I need.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I meant by a complete example *document*. We need to know *how* you cite your entries as well. Please follow the two links in my comment above and create a complete example.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. The document structure is quite simple.  
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{comment} 
  \usepackage{fullpage} 

  \begin{document}
  \section{Section}
  \subsection{Subsection}
  Text \cite{ofori2014impact}

  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{bibfile}

  \end{document}

Comment: Please add this to your question, so that it is self contained. Please also test your MWE in an empty directory to make sure that it gives the output you claim to see.

Comment: Okay, so I did run this in an empty directory and everything looked fine. So I just copied the rest of the tex file there and it works like it's supposed to. Not sure what the problem was, but you fixed it. Thanks so much for help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments